# Focus out and submit event firing order

Tags: javascript

I have a form with an input field , input field is attached a focus out event handler 
I have also a form submit handler attached with the form, so when user focus out of input  box then its 
focus out handler executes that's fine but when form is submitted then also focus out event on input box is fired. So how can i prevent this?

Help is appreciated :)

```
Demo code
<form>
    <input type='text' name='test'/>
</form>


$('input').focusout(function(){
alert('focus out');
});

$('form').submit(function(){
    alert('form submitted');
    return false;
});
```

when i run above code in firefox and chrome output is different
**firefox** : *focus out is alerted first followed by form submitted*
**chrome** : *form submitted is alerted first followed by focus out*
why is it behaving differently in both browser , i want to prevent focus out on form submit .

Comment: Your question lacks a question.

Comment: @GolezTrol The question is there: _how can I prevent this?_

Comment: @Barmar With the addition that became clear, yes.

Answer (score 1):

You can only focus one element at a time, so probably when you click your submit button it is being focused automatically and all other elements inside the form are getting focused out and thats where your event is being fired.

What you are doing doesn't look like a nicest solution to achieve any goal, please tell us what you are trying to do and we will probably working out something better.

Comment: but my form is being submitted by enter press , i have no button in my form

Comment: Pressing enter in the last field in a form focuses out of that field, just like tabbing out, and then submits the form.

Answer (score 1):

To make browser behavior even worse. `IE` only fires the submit event on enter and negates the focusout event. (I find this desired behavior), since hitting an <kbd>enter</kbd> button, shouldn't cause the input to lose focus.

You can't really predict which event is fired first in this case.

To prevent this you should have a `keydown` event on the form, which detects user keyboard input and when the last input is focused. If so then prevent all events and submit.

```
$('input').focusout(function(e){
    alert("Focusout gets fired.");
});

$('form').keydown(function(e){

    if (e && e.target == $('input')[0] && e.keyCode == 13) //13 = enter.
    {
        //submit the form, and in case something goes wrong, prevent default.
        $('form')[0].submit();
        e.preventDefault();
    }

});
```

Sidenote: your `form` has one `input`. Only to prove that this works I used `$('form')[0]` and `$('input')[0]` to select the elements. In a real form you want to provide these values through `id` selectors.